# Audio amplifier : how to combine stereo output to mono input

Tags: amplifier, audio, raspberry-pi, pcm

In the following schematic, I would like to decode PCM audio from my Raspberry Pi and output the signal to a 3W speaker. The [PAM8302](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/PAM8302A.pdf) datasheet is quite light. I don't understand what the input levels are. On the other hand, the PCM5100A PCM decoder offers a 2.1 Vrms stereo output with a 1kOhm load impedance.

[image]

I would like to properly connect the decoder to the amplifier without a potentiometer. Any idea?

Comment: Where did you get that diagram?  R45 looks like a really bad idea.  A potentiometer is not (in general) a bad idea, it is just that R45 is connected rather strangely.

Comment: I got this from a random internet forum. What do you propose instead of R45? Putting IN- to GND and IN+ directly to OUTL and OUT R?

Comment: As U21 seems to have internal biasing to its mid-supply, one way would be to remove R45, feed into IN+ via C61 and leave IN- open. A better way would be to invert OUTR (digitally or with opamp) and feed that separately into IN- via C62. This will double to mono output amplitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet clearly states the closed-loop gain :

> Maximum Gain :
> As shown in block diagram (Page 2), the PAM8302A differential gain for the IC is :
> A = 20*log (RF/RI).
> The PAM8302A sets maximum RF = 150kΩ, minimum RI = 10kΩ, so the maximum closed-gain around 23.5dB. If need gain adjustment, you can put
> external RIN at the input pin, and gain calculate as 20*log (150K/ (10K+RIN)).

So you can reduce gain to adjust best dynamic range if required by adding x2 Rin on each + and - inputs. Otherwise if you require more gain you would need extra amplifiers to do that, but I presume the desired purpose of the pot is to reduce the gain so that max input occurs at max output with minimum distortion etc.

Answer (score 1):

The connection of R45 looks very odd.  I would expect the bottom end of the potentiometer to be connected to ground (and still connected to IN-).

If you don't want a potentiometer, replace it with two fixed resistors.  If you aren't sure how to do the gain calculations, the easiest solution is to temporarily use a potentiometer.  Adjust the volume until it sounds right, then remove the potentiometer *without turning the shaft on it*, and measure the resistances from the centre to the two ends with a multimeter.  that gives you the two fixed resistors to use.